# Install ZendOAuth

Tags: php, zend-framework, oauth, zend-framework2

Apologies if this is a very basic question.  But I'm quite new to PHP and the Zend Framework.  And I've searched and searched for help with this and am getting nowhere!

In short I need to use the ZendOAuth library in a Zend Framework 2.3 web application.  I've downloaded the zip file for this library from GitHub.  So far so good.

But what exactly do you do with that zip file??  The documentation for this is next to nothing, or at least very unclear to me.

Do you need to unzip it to a specific place within my application?  And then what do you do with it?  Run the 2 commands that are mentioned on GitHub, i.e.:

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar install
```

And is that it?  I should then be able to use classes within that library?

Is there a general principle I'm not understanding here for how you install libraries into Zend?  This seems like a very basic thing to be able to do, but I'm finding it very difficult to get a simple explanation on how these things work with ZF2.  Could well be just me though :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download Zip
2. Extract It
3. Put it under vendor \ zendframework directory.
4. Add path in vendor \ composer \ autoload_namespace.php  => You can use other existed entries for your example.

Comment: Great, that's done it.  Thanks so much.  (I would +1 but I don't the required reputation yet I'm afraid)